# Communication between tenant network and existing network in openstack

Tags: networking, router, openstack

I am trying to make the tenant network communicate with an existing network which did not build in OpenStack. we all know we can allocate a floating IP to VM with external network, but now we have no need access Internet, so we would not allocate IP to VM, just want to make tenant VM can communicate with another network, how do I map the existing network to OpenStack and create router between them?
Any help would be appreciated.Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are certain steps to do this.

You need to add a routing entry for the tenant network in compute nodes.

You need to use Masquerading on compute node.

I think with this configuration you will be able to establish communication between tenant network and existing physical network.